# What happened to the broken link review queue?

Tags: discussion, review, hyperlinks

For a bit there was a sort of "beta" review queue for broken links at `yoursite.se/review/links`, you can still see the stats for that queue at https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/links/stats. However trying to review more bad links gives me a 404 page. I assume the queue was taken down.

What happened to that queue and are we ever going to see it again? I thought it was awesome, it really helped out AU (never knew we had so many bad links!).

Comment: I didn't know this existed! I would love to see this reactivated because I *hate* dead links.

Comment: We'd probably want the "flag" link disabled on any posts that are in that queue.  For our sanity, and apparently your safety. :)

Comment: @BilltheLizard You get a lot of broken link flags on SO? That's odd, but understandable.

Comment: We currently only get a few. Many people proactively flag link-only answers because they *could* become broken links someday, so I imagine we'd get a lot more flags if these posts were all conveniently exposed.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Maybe if the queue got rolled out again they could implement a feature that allows you to "recommend deletion" or at least flag answers that are x characters short that appear in the queue. Link only answer != broken link answer however. Although they do overlap.

Answer (score 21):

They should re-implement that, but only allow editing, or arrange it so that editing is heavily emphasized.  The reviewers would be required to hunt down the correct links and fix them, if they could.  Of course, like all review queues there would be the 3 badges associated with them, so there'd be some incentive.

Comment: IMO they should allow more than just editing. What if the link is completely broken and the answer becomes unsalvageable? Now I have to open a new tab to downvote, vote to delete and/or flag? Doesn't sound optimal to me.

Comment: @ɥʇǝS, I was painting with a broad brush.  It should mainly be used for fixing links, but there could be some ancillary functionality.

Comment: Ah, in that case, yes I do think they should bring it back.

Comment: @ɥʇǝS, edited..