# Could we prevent link rot by locally caching outgoing links?

Tags: feature-request, broken-link

Amber is a new tool currently in beta that claims to be able to fix broken links. You can read a news article about it [here](http://www.macworld.com/article/2880370/amber-enlists-websites-to-help-banish-broken-links.html) and check out its actual website [here](http://amberlink.org). Long story short, it's like "a decentralized Wayback Machine" that *locally* caches every outgoing link posted.

Can we get this on Stack Exchange?

Comment: You might want to think about rewording this a bit, especially the title. I was two seconds away from flagging this question as spam.

Comment: Somehow I'm not sure if SE is really going to be capable of caching every single page linked to from its network.  That'd be extremely resource demanding, given SE's size.

Comment: As a suggestion for improving the question: perhaps start by presenting a *problem* that you feel the SE network currently has, and then describe how the tool would fix that problem; rather than starting with the description of the tool, which feels "spammy."

Comment: Disregarding technical issues and consequences, never mind legal ones, I'd say that addresses the problem on the wrong end. You'd better focus on getting posts self-contained rather than trying to have a copy of whatever external content the post relies on.

Comment: Locally caching every link on SE?  Lol.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238956/automatically-backup-the-content-of-links-to-prevent-linkrot

Answer (score 8):

Like [Bart](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/161198/bart) said in a [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248221/could-we-prevent-link-rot-by-locally-caching-outgoing-links#comment813097_248221), this shouldn't be too much of a problem. If a link dies, the content should *already be* included in the answer, so that the link should not be necessary anymore.

If you find that there is a widespread problem of ["link-only" answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/266359) on your SE sites, you should either edit those answers to include the important information, or flag it as "not an answer."

That said; as [Servy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/186381/servy) pointed [out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248221/could-we-prevent-link-rot-by-locally-caching-outgoing-links#comment813086_248221), this would be a massive undertaking, which would involve a *lot* of resources that SE just might not have. There are a *lot* of links around, and caching them all is a lot of information that, as mentioned above, shouldn't really be needed.

I don't think that this feature is a good, or necessary, idea.