# Automatically detect broken links in old posts and add them to the review queue

Tags: feature-request, review, hyperlinks, broken-link

Some questions and answers on Stack Exchange have broken links. And sometimes those are important links in accepted or most upvoted answers. However unless someone leaves a comment about the broken link or edits the post, they often go unnoticed for many months.

Could Stack Exchange implement a bot to track down broken links ([similar to the Wikipedia one](https://blog.wikimedia.org/2016/10/26/internet-archive-broken-links/))? Flagged posts would then be added to the review queue and users would have a chance to update the links. On sites like Stack Overflow this could be limited to highly-upvoted posts to reduce the workload, others could get all the flagged questions without filters.

Comment: Related but slightly different (comments vs. review queue): https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50999/so-should-notify-users-of-broken-links-in-their-posts

Comment: This has been done before as experiment, and has failed. Doubt they will do it again.

Comment: Almost dupe: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71529/can-we-have-some-tools-to-handle-link-rot.

Comment: We already getting many `suggested edits` saying _Fixed broken link_ and we check the link and _Approve/Reject_ it. I think it is difficult to identify some broken links. Because some broken links points to a **404** whereas some sites points to **Home**. So, for a bot, it is very difficult

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224895/what-happened-to-the-broken-link-review-queue